# how to get the value of a kendoui dropdown list selected value in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

am having Some kendoui listviews which consists of kendoui dropdown lists and i want to get those dropdown list selected values. To do this am trying,

```
 $("#cnty1").val();
```

and here is my dropdownlist,i.e., list of countries coming from Database table,

```
<input select STYLE="width:90px;height:auto" id ="cnty1" data-bind="value:cnty1" 
name="cnty1" data-type="string" data-text-field="cnty" 
data-value-field="cntyid" data-source="sourcedata1" class="k-d"   
data-role="dropdownlist" />

<span data-for="cnty1" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
```

here cnty1 is the id of the dropdown list, but am not getting the value instead am getting "id" of the slected value but not the selected value.

And also if the value is not selected am getting the first value id by using `$("#cnty1").val();`

So, please suggest me a solution so that,
1) I should get only the Selected value and 
2) Value of the dropdown list Only if the user selects a value from the list, but don't get the value of the list without selecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one.

```
<select STYLE="width:90px;height:auto" id ="cnty1" data-bind="value:cnty1" 
data-text-field="cnty" data-value-field="cntyid" data-source="sourcedata1" data-role="dropdownlist" data-change="cntySelect" data-option-label="Select"></select>

function cntySelect(e) {                                                
          var dropDownVal = $("#cnty1").val();
            alert(dropDownVal);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following jquery to get selected value/text:

For **value**:
`$("#cnty1 option:selected").val();`

For **text** use:
`$("#cnty1 option:selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks for your your answer but,                                    for value:  $("#cnty1 option:selected").val(); am getting "undefined" and for text:$("#cnty1 option:selected").text(); not getting anything.

Comment: Hi its because the name of your dropdown is cnty1. Its not id.So please give some valid id to dropdown e.g id="cntDropDown" and use it in jquery like : $("#cntDropDown option:selected").val();

Answer (score 0):

Although this code is being used for FK JSON objects in KendoUI grid, the idea is similar. You have to bind the object on dropdown value selection. The dropdown essentially contains options that are your value ID's, not the objects themselves. Therefore, you have to iterate through the data source to find which object has been selected and then do the replacement in data model.

```
/**
 * KendoDropDownEditor Class
 * */
var KendoDropDownEditor = Class({

    initialize: function (schema, gridId, readUrl) {

        var readUrl = readUrl || base + schema.entityName + "/read";
        this.dataSource = DataSourceGenerator.crudDS(schema, gridId, readUrl);

        this.dataTextField = schema.model.dropDownTextField;
        this.dataValueField = schema.model.id;
    },

    /**
     *
     * */
    do:function (container, options) {
        var self = this;
        var a = $('<input data-text-field="' + self.dataTextField + '" data-value-field="' + self.dataValueField + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind:false,
                dataSource:self.dataSource,
                close:function (e) {
                    $.each(self.dataSource.data(), function(key, value) {
                        if (value[self.dataValueField] == e.sender.value()) {
                            options.model[options.field] = value;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Also look at [Knockout-Kendo](http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/DropDownList.html), it could make your life easier.